# Can Google Analytics track WeChat as a traffic source?

Tags: google-analytics

The site in question has a Chinese language page and uses WeChat as a marketing tool. Since google web traffic is blocked in China, how would that effect referral traffic showing up in Google analytics channels from WeChat links? Also, would UTM parameters help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referral traffic and organic traffic are different channels so it should be fine. If you want to make sure that Google attributes the traffic to the right channel you can set that up by going to:

Admin -> View -> Channel Settings -> Channel Groupings -> Default Channel Grouping OR New Channel Grouping.

From there you will be able to add your WeChat traffic referrals by utilizing one of many available dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @dasickle. I was actually more concerned with the fact that China blocks Google and whether that would stop analytics from tracking the referral correctly in any way? So are you saying that is not an issue? Currently I have not been able to find any reference to WeChat in the referral URLs